# Journey entry event split - cannot split by registration date

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have created a smart capture form on a cloud page and would like users who fill in the form to go on a different engagement path (using journey decision split) based on the date in which they submit the form (click register)

Is there any way this can be done? I can't see any entry event that supports this.

Comment: What type of entry event are you using? Data Extension or Cloud Page?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the data extension to which data is posted in your entry event, and the submission timestamp is recorded in one of the columns, you can find it under Journey Data in your decision split.

If you provide additional context (e.g. how you connect your data to the journey, your data model and what fields are recorded upon submission), I can elaborate on my answer.